# I´m having problems with a defined function

Tags: python, function, user-defined-functions

I´m trying to create a functions that sorts a list of numbers and splits the list in two lists: one for even numbers and another one for odd numbers, I don´t understand what I´m doing wrong:

```
numbers = [-12, 84, 13, 20, -33, 101, 9]

def separated(list_numbers):

    numbers = numbers.sort()    
    list_even_numbers = []
    list_odd_numbers = []

    for number in numbers:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            list_even_numbers.append(number)
        else:
            list_odd_numbers.append(number)

    return list_even_numbers, list_odd_numbers


list_even_numbers, list_odd_numbers = separated(numbers)
print(list_even_numbers)
print(list_odd_numbers)
```

And this is the error message I receive:

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-35d3975ff0c1> in <module>
   16 
   17 
-> 18 list_even_numbers, list_odd_numbers = separated(numbers)
   19 print(list_even_numbers)
   20 print(list_odd_numbers)

<ipython-input-43-35d3975ff0c1> in separated(list_numbers)
   3 def separated(list_numbers):
   4 
-> 5     numbers = numbers.sort()
   6     list_even_numbers = []
   7     list_odd_numbers = []

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'numbers' referenced before assignment
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first line in the function should be `list_numbers = sorted(list_numbers)`

Comment: You should replace `numbers` with  `list_numbers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below:

```
numbers = [-12, 84, 13, 20, -33, 101, 9]

def separated(list_numbers):

    list_numbers.sort()    
    list_even_numbers = []
    list_odd_numbers = []

    for number in list_numbers:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            list_even_numbers.append(number)
        else:
            list_odd_numbers.append(number)

    return list_even_numbers, list_odd_numbers


list_even_numbers, list_odd_numbers = separated(numbers)
print(list_even_numbers)
print(list_odd_numbers)
```

Comment: Please explain what you changed and why…

Comment: I changed your this line numbers = numbers.sort()  to  list_numbers.sort() since you are using your function parameter and not the array defined outside